# PowerShell script for deleting files and folders of specific criteria

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to write a script that will search for:

1. Folders with specific names.
2. Files with specific extensions while
3. Excluding certain directories from the search.

Once the search is performed, I'd like all the 1s and 2s to be deleted as well as the parent folders if they don't match 3. Here's what I have so far:

```
#Define list of computers to search for the files and folders in question
$ComputerList = Get-Content -Path "C:\computers.txt"

#Define a function for searching files and folders based on criteria:
function search {
    PROCESS {
        $srcFolder ="C:\test"
        Get-ChildItem $srcFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  -recurse -Force | Where-Object {`
            $_.Name -eq “keyword1” -or`
            $_.Name -eq “keyword2” -or`

              -and $_.fullname -notmatch 'C:\\Windows'`
              -and $_.fullname -notmatch 'C:\\Program Files'
        } | foreach-object -process { _.FullName }
    }
}

foreach ($strComputer in $ComputerList)
{
    #Perform the search function on all the computers listed
    foreach ($objItem in $colItems)
    {
        write-host         "-------------------------$strComputer ----------------" -foregroundcolor "red"
        write-host         "                      Files Found                                                    " -foregroundcolor "yellow" -backgroundcolor "black"
             $ComputerList | search

        "Number of files and folders found: " +($ComputerList | search | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count)
        write-host "------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor "red"
    }

    if (($ComputerList | search).count -lt 1) {
        write-host "No files found to delete"
    }
    else {
        #Prompt if you want to delete the files
        write-host         "Do you want to delete these files?" -foregroundcolor "yellow" -backgroundcolor "black"
        $ComputerList | search | Remove-Item -Force -confirm
    }
}
Out-File -FilePath C:\results.txt
```

So here are the issues I'm having:

1. I can get the script to work. However, I'm not sure how to go about deleting the parent folder while protecting the excluded ones.
2. The output to the file is not working. The file gets created, but it's blank. Why?

After looking at `Get-ChildItem | Get-Member`, I realized that the Parent property is specified by System.IO.DirectoryInfo Parent, so if I can add that to the list of items to be deleted then it should work.

The folder structure is below. To reiterate in a perhaps clearer way, I want to delete a folder:

1. Whose name or content matches keyword(s)
2. If the content matches keyword(s), but the folder's name does not > check to see if it's explicitly excluded e.g. C:\Windows, C:\Program Files etc. > If it is, leave alone. If it's not, delete the folder.**

Here are the plain URLs:

```
oi42.tinypic.com/2nulmz4.jpg
oi43.tinypic.com/fwlxd0.jpg
oi42.tinypic.com/315hdw9.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it simple:

```
$folder = "C:\pst"
$excludedFolders = "c:\Windows", "c:\PST\new"

$itemsFromFolder = get-childitem $folder -recurse
$itemsToDelete = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

foreach ($item in $itemsFromFolder)
{
    $exclude = $false
    foreach ($exclusion in $excludedFolders)
    {
        if ($item.FullName.ToLower().StartsWith($exclusion.ToLower()))
        {
            $exclude = $true
        }
    }
    if (!$exclude)
    {
        $itemsToDelete.Add($item.FullName)
    }
}
```

As you can see you can define what folders you need to exclude upfront and then sort all your items, filtering out directories that should be kept. You can then exclude also some paths, or extensions with Remove-Item:

```
Remove-Item c:\scripts\* -include *.txt -exclude *test*
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would like for the parent to be deleted as well if it contains a folder or file containing the keywords specified.

Comment: In other words, I want to delete both as long as they don't match the paths I'm excluding i.e. the Windows folder etc.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm afraid that this doesn't include deleting the parent folder if you don't know their name. The users will be creating folders containing files / other folders searched by the keywords above. I have no way of knowing the names of parent folders, just their contents, so I cannot explicitly include them. Is there some generic way of including parent folders such as "../"?